# Unsupport characters in command line file path

Tags: java, php, command-line-interface

I would linke to call java app from PHP:

```
exec('LC_ALL=en_US.utf-8 java -jar /test.jar' . $filepath . ');
```

But always there are unsupported characters in the file path.

For example: # & ; ? * [SPACE]..., after change them to # \& ... it will be ok.

But a full list of these characters could not be find.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [`escapeshellcmd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php).

They will take care of all necessary sanitation for you.

If `$filepath` comes from the outside (e.g. from user input), running `escapeshellarg()` is **mandatory** to prevent injections.

Comment: This file name always show java error 44248-1 (ru) v01 - обращение ЕА_каталог экспорт.doc

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: inputFile doesn't exist: 44248-1 (ru) v01 -  _ .doc

Comment: @bruce that's a different issue, most likely a character set problem because of the cyrillic characters. That's much more complex. Worth a separate question

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved.

Useful url:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44945